# getting Data From SQLite Database;

Tags: iphone

Unable to get Data..

```
- (void)getAmountFromDB
{
    expensesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *destinationPath = [self getDestinationPath];

    const char *dbpath = [destinationPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"month String is = %@",monthString);
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT breakFastAmt,lunchAmt,dinnerAmt,dailyTravelAmt,outStationTravelAmt FROM TABLE_For_Expenses WHERE month=\"%@\"",monthString];


        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSLog(@"hi");
                }
```

Flow Not Entering in following condition.

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

BUT its Working For Following Code;

```
- (void) getDataFromDB
{
    expensesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *destinationPath = [self getDestinationPath];

    const char *dbpath = [destinationPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM TABLE_For_Expenses"];


        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                           NSLog (@"hi");
                        }
               }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use CoreData instead?

Comment: FMDB is a cool option though ..

Comment: You may like to NSLog querySQL and check if it is ok .. also you may try the first scenario without the WHERE clause and see what happens .

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with ur sql statment try this :

```
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT breakFastAmt,lunchAmt,dinnerAmt,dailyTravelAmt,outStationTravelAmt FROM TABLE_For_Expenses WHERE month= '%@'",monthString];
```