# How to print all data in given table?

Tags: iphone

i am iPhone application developer, and now we understood the concept of database.
i want to print all data from database. but i m not getting how can i print all data. here is i pest some code. please give me correct direction to print all data..

for example in sql we print all data as "select * from contact5;" we fire this string. can we done in iPhone coding?

```
-(IBAction)PrintData:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement1;



    NSString *querySQL=@"SELECT * FROM CONTACT5";


    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];


    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement1, NULL);

    while (sqlite3_step(statement1) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {

        NSLog(@"Enter in  the denger zone");
        NSString *idField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 0)];

        NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 2)];

        NSString *NameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 1)];

        NSString *phoneFiels = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement1, 3)];

        NSLog(@"ID is=%@",idField);

        NSLog(@"Name is=%@",NameField);
        NSLog(@"Address is=%@",addressField);
        NSLog(@"Phone No. is=%@",phoneFiels);


        [idField release];
        [NameField release];
        [phoneFiels release];
        [addressField release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement1);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want? can't get you do you want to show the output to the user? If yes then use UITableView to do so.

Comment: Your NSLog stmts looks fine & seems working good. What is your problem.? Pls make it clear if you are getting any warnings/errors

Comment: for example in sql we print all data as "select * from contact5;" we fire this string. can we done in iPhone coding?

Comment: As far as i know select * from tableName will not print but it will get you a table.If you want to save your data for later use. Make use of NSMutableDictionary to save all your contacts and make use to UITableView to display all contacts to the user

Comment: i want to print all data in a table. for example we use sql,their is a  statement to print all data in table, as "select * from Table_name". so can we write down as that type of string in iPhone. please explain briefly..

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272791/getting-data-from-sqlite-database) link to get all data from table.

Answer (score 0):

We are sharing Some come which is using NSMutableDictionary to store your data and you can easily use that code to print your data,where do you want

```
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "Select * from CalculateTime";

        sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error: Failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        arrayCountry = nil;
        arrayCountry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        arrayCity = nil;
        arrayCity = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        arrayFlag = nil;
        arrayFlag = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        arrayZone = nil;
        arrayZone = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        NSString *str2;

        while(sqlite3_step(insertStmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {

            char *row;

            row = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(insertStmt, 0);
            if(row != NULL)
            {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row];
                [arrayCountry addObject:str2];
            }

            row = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(insertStmt, 1);
            if(row != NULL)
            {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row];
                [arrayCity addObject:str2];
            }


            row = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(insertStmt, 2);
            if(row != NULL)
            {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row];
                [arrayFlag addObject:str2];
            }

            row = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(insertStmt, 3);
            if(row != NULL)
            {
                str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:row];
                [arrayZone addObject:str2];
            }

        }
    }
```

Access these dictionary data to print anywhere..